# Split function contract template

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson, smartpy, ligo

Is there a code template for a simple contract which splits the incoming funds and sends them proportionally to a list of pre-registered addresses?

Example:
Contract has the following functions:

- `register(address):admin` stores a given tz123 address
- `deregister(address):admin` removes the given tz123 address from the
  storage
- `main()` receives incoming tez, splits the amount and
  sends them to each registered address

The idea is to create a bucket of donation addresses of Tezos related services so that a person can donate tez to this contract and the contract donates to all the services. This way the person does not have to create 30+ transactions by himself if he wants to support the Tezos ecosystem.